# Why the Fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Please help. What happens? What is the cause of error, and how could I solve it? Thanks for your help!

```
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.interviewhelpers/com.example.interviewhelpers.Dashboard}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #192: Error
> inflating class fragment


Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #192: Error inflating class fragment
```

This is my code: Main class...

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
```

activity_dashboard... Has more elements and layouts, and this:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.interviewhelpers.ClientDetailActivity" ></fragment>
```

And...

```
 package com.example.interviewhelpers;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ClientDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cliente_detailed, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Always try to use the support libraries as you are doing)
First: 
1. Should use a FragmentActivity and NO Activity
2. Should use a Fragment to the child components you'll be using.
3. On the Fragments on the onCreateView just do the Inflate
4. On the Fragment use the onViewCreated to find the TextView.
Sample:
//This is the Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }    
}
```

//This is the layout.activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.fragmentapp.ChildFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

//This is the Fragment to be shown

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_frag, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView tvText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tvText.setText("Found!");
    }
}
```

//This is the layout for the fragment layout.child_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```