# Can't load FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried creating an Android app. using tabs in Android Studio. I ran into the issue where all my fragment imports were causing the error `Cannot Resolve Symbol 'FragmentManager'`, and anything else associated with fragments within my program. I made sure I was importing the correct support files:

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

[image: Image of Errors]

I checked to make sure I was calling active fragments in my layout files, similar issue explained [**[here]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838333/why-the-fragment-doesnt-work).

I made sure I had the latest Android SDK Build-tools, shown **[[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16608570/1461021)**.

I [**[re-synced the Gradle Files]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212070/sync-project-with-gradle-files).

```
    Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

I even imported a pre-made application from the Android Developer guides, [**[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs]**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), and the error was not going away. Which made me think that there was possibly something wrong with Android Studio. I recently updated to  Version 0.8.14 and I noticed the file structure changed a bit, it is now more streamlined.

[image: Application Structure]

Which lead me back to poke around within the gradle files. I opened up the build.gradle and verified that there were no issues from the minSdk version and then did one last check on possible errors with Gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Check out my answer for the **[[solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26856201/1461021)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this was not my question, I stumbled upon **[[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887180/android-studio-build-error-with-appcompat-library-newbie-q/19888036#19888036)** thread, that suggests that you add other dependencies to the build for the support build library. Add this line within the dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
```

(For more clarification, using the previous code, you would add this beneath the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']`).

Once you've added this, Android Studio would point out the gradle files have changed and that you should re-sync them. Once the sync is complete, it should resolve the not being able to find the fragments!

[image: Gradle Sync]

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

For those facing this error in June 2019 upwards, make sure that if you are using the now new androidX library, you must make change ***android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager*** anywhere you call the library in your code to ***androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager***

Answer (score 1):

For those of you stumbling across this now you may be interested to know that the support library had a *split* in version `24.2.0` *(August 2016)*:

> **Note:** *Prior to Support Library revision 24.2.0, there was a single v4 support library. That library was divided into multiple modules to improve efficiency. For backwards compatibility, if you list support-v4 in your Gradle script, your APK will include all of the v4 modules. However, to reduce APK size, we recommend that you just list the specific modules your app needs.*

**v4 compat library**

```
com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0
```

**v4 core-utils library**

```
com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0
```

**v4 core-ui library**

```
com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0
```

**v4 media-compat library**

```
com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.0
```

**v4 fragment library**

```
com.android.support:support-fragment:24.2.0
```

---

Reference:

[Developer.Android.com](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor)